# Jenkins: Subproject Builds are not shown for a Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Project which acts as an "entry project" and is triggering other projects. 
Now running builds on this entry projects I get on every build a link under "Subproject Builds" to the child projects.

I have now written a new Job and added this also to the "entry project" but for this project I dont see any link on the builds under "Subproject Builds".

Does someone know what needs to be configured that the child Job communicates the link back to the parent Project?

Comment: I think you should execute the project with new job at least once. Then you'll see a link to the new job.

Comment: I have done this but unfortunately no success. in the log I see this: - Waiting for the completion of {JOBLING}
Build step 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' changed build result to SUCCESS-  But running the Parent job one thime with Job A, I get a link and one time with Job B I dont get a link :(

Comment: I see now a diffrence the SubProject which reports the information back is called as "Static" in the parent job overview the job which is not is called "Unresolved"